# Parse return object

Tags: parse-platform

How do I return the Sequence object from the private function when called from parse cloud function.

```
function getNextMemberId() {
    var id = -1;
    var Zseq = Parse.Object.extend("ZSeqMember");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Zseq);

    var IncObj;
    query.get("lcnm8AZWFK", {
        success: function (object) {
            object.increment("Seq");
            object.save(null,
                {
                    success: function (object) {  },
                    error: function (object, error) { return Parse.Promise.error(error); }
                }
            );
        }, error: function (object, error) {
            console.log(error);
            return Parse.Promise.error(error);
        }
    });

//I want to return the Object, which contains "Seq" column.      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because you don't have it when the function finishes, because the request to get it is asynchronous. You need to change `getNextMemberId` so it includes a completion closure when can be used to 'return' the object once it's available.